# ¿Se puede condicionar con If un array dentro de un foreach en PHP?

Tags: php, html

Soy muy nuevo en `PHP` y me encontré con un problema el cual no encuentro mucha información, algo que realmente entienda o que me ayude para mi nivel; tengo **dos FOREACH** (Los cuales nunca he usado en otro lenguaje), estos imprimen una tabla en `HTML` y necesito ignorar por completo el último campo (QUIERO QUE SE MUESTREN TODOS LOS DATOS, MENOS EL ÚLTIMO DE CADA CICLO **["G. Img"]**); he intentado el **CONTINUE;** pero **realmente el problema es el If**, no me funciona con nada; he probado demasiadas formas.

***ACÁ DEJO MI PEQUEÑO CÓDIGO SIN FUNCIONAR:***

```
<?php

    foreach($paises As $x){

    //DEBERÍA IGNORAR EL ÚLTIMO DATO Y SEGUIR EL CICLO
    //INTENTO FALLIDO:
    if(array_keys($x) == 6){
        echo "Entró";
        continue;
    }

    foreach($x As $x1){
        //CÓDIGO PARA IMPRIMIR LOS DATOS INTERNOS DE LOS PAÍSES.
        //-------------
        //-------------
    }
                
}?>
```

***Además adjunto la forma de mis arrays asociativos:***

```
$paises = array(

    "Chile" => array(
        "Bandera" => "<img src='../SOURCES/cl.png'>",
        "Nombre"  => "República de Chile",
        "Moneda"  => "CLP",
        "Comida" => "Ajiaco","Chorillana","Sopaipillas",
        "G. Img" => "<img src='1.png'>", "<img src='1.png'>", "<img src='1.png'>"
    ),

    "Japón" => array(
        "Bandera" => "<img src='../SOURCES/jp.png'>",
        "Nombre"  => "Estado del Japón",
        "Moneda"  => "YEN",
        "Comida" => "Ramen","Onigiri","Yakitori",
        "G. Img" => "<img src='1.png'>", "<img src='1.png'>", "<img src='1.png'>"
    );
```

Gracias de antemano :( !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, la condición para la salida debería estar en el segundo `foreach`, no en el primero, ya que es en el segundo donde recorres los datos de los países.

Segundo, en este caso quieres evitar un elemento concreto, que resulta que es el último del array. Te va a ser más fácil evitar ese elemento por su key, ya que sabes cuál es `G. Img`.

Para eso puedes valerte de incluir `$key` en el `foreach`:

```
foreach ($paises as $datos) {
    foreach ($datos as $key => $val) {
        if ($key !== 'G. Img') {
            //CÓDIGO PARA IMPRIMIR EL DATO $val
            //echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br />';
        }
    }        
}
```

No obstante, también te pongo cómo hacerlo excluyendo el último elemento, para eso necesitas un contador:

```
foreach ($paises as $datos) {
    $c = 0;
    $count = count($datos);

    foreach ($datos => $val) {
        $c++;

        if ($c == $count) {
            break; //¡Ojo! Aquí es break lo que necesitas, no continue
        }

        //CÓDIGO PARA IMPRIMIR EL DATO $val
        //¡Ojo! Aquí no tienes la $key (puedes añadirla al foreach)
    }        
}
```

También podrías usar un bucle `for` normal, donde ya declararías el contador, pero bueno, no te lío más. El primer ejemplo es la mejor solución.

Otra cosa, seguramente quieras pintar el nombre de cada país, para eso puedes usar `$key` también en el primer bucle. Pero a esa `$key` la vamos a llamar `$pais`, así es más claro y además no te colisiona con el nombre de variable `$key` del segundo bucle. Con lo que te quedaría así:

```
foreach ($paises as $pais => $datos) {
    //CÓDIGO PARA IMPRIMIR EL NOMBRE DEL PAIS
    echo '<b>' . $pais . '</b><br />';

    foreach ($datos as $key => $val) {
        if ($key !== 'G. Img') {
            //CÓDIGO PARA IMPRIMIR EL DATO $val
            echo $key . ': ' . $val . '<br />';
        }
    }

    //UN SALTO DE LINEA
    echo '<br />';
}
```

**Nota**: He puesto *echoes* muy simples como ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó con un pequeño ajuste bien barato; pues el elemento que quería eliminar en general es todo el array "G. Img":
*
if($c == $count - 2){ 
    break;
}

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Otra opción en lugar de utilizar un contador es utilizar la función `end` que verifica si un elemento está al final de un arreglo:

```
foreach ($paises as $datos) {
    foreach ($datos as $key => $val) {
        // Revisamos si el elemento $val está al final del arreglo $datos
        // Si es así, interrumpimos el foreach con break
        if ($val == end($datos)) break;
        printf($key);
    }        
}
```

Esto imprime las llaves de todos los elementos menos el último.

```
BanderaNombreMonedaComidaBanderaNombreMonedaComida
```

**Nota:** no tiene formato ni nada, solo fue un ejemplo simple.

**Nota adicional:** Si tu controlas la información y orden del arreglo, podrías utilizar algún método para descartar el último elemento del arreglo, pero si es probable que tengan orden diferente entonces yo creo que la mejor opción sería buscar la llave como menciona @JoseCarlosPHP en su primer ejemplo.